# window.showModalDialog is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code to showModalDialog popup:---

.aspx code is:-

```
function ShowPopup(path) {
     window.showModalDialog(path, '', 'dialogWidth:700px; dialogHeight:530px; Center:yes');
}
```

My aspx.cs code is:--

```
switch (e.CommandName.ToLower())
{
    case "sendenquiry":
        string path = string.Format("/BusinessBazaarAspx/PopUps/Enquiry.aspx?c={0}", id);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(gvLatestCompanies, GetType(), "mykey2",
                                                string.Format("ShowPopup('{0}')", path), true);
         break;
```

But my Modal Popup is not visible...

Help me to get rid of this problem.

Thankx

Comment: Try to bring up the java console and see what error you receive in the browser when you are trying to execute your action. Also, a little bit more code from your .aspx page would be very helpfull.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my previous comment, but it would be important to see, how you include the script in your .aspx page. Meaning that it would be beneficial to see the opening and closing script tags (for this script block) and everything between...